# Unable to parse html of a website using Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to collect the **href** ([click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ipzh.png)) from the website, https://www.groupeactual.eu/offre-emploi using python and BeautifulSoup module. But for some reason I am not being able to parse the particular html data. What is the solution to this problem. Thanks in advance !

Here is my code,

```
response = requests.get("https://www.groupeactual.eu/offre-emploi").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")
soup1 = soup.find_all("div", class_="js-result-annonce")
soup1
```

[click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ipzh.png)

Answer (score 0):

The websites uses ajax to load the search results. You can see it in the inspector (F12 in Chrome Browser):

[image: Networking tab in chrome inspector]

So you probably need inspect the posted data which is sent to https://www.groupeactual.eu/offre-emploi/search and try to make these requests with your scraper script.

Comment: Hello there, I am actually new to web scraping so excuse me for any rookie errors. So what I should do I inspect using a different method then gather the html using scraper ?

Comment: I want to actualy collect the red circled link in the image I attached actually. How should I do that ?

Comment: This seems non-trivial with BeatufilSoup as there seems be some _token is used for the ajax requests. if you need to scrape the page only once, maybe some Chrome-Extension is more appropriate tool here. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/scraper

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
soup.findAll("div", {"class": "js-result-annonce"})
```

Comment: This does not give the nested info !

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
table = soup.select('div', attrs={"class":"js-result-annonce"})
```

Comment: Thanks for helping resolve the issue. Could you also help readers understand the problem and solution better by explaining *why* and *how* this works?